# Apply stock quote changes using observer pattern

Tags: c#, observer-pattern

I am implementing observer pattern(refering codeproject) for stock quote update. I have created an interface for Subject and Observer. I have created instances for Subject and Observer and also the functionality to register, notify and update. Kindly let me know the approach is correct

```
public  interface IObserver
    {
        void update(double value);
    }
}
```

//subject

```
public interface ISubject
    {
         void Register(IObserver o);
         void UnRegister(IObserver o);
         void notify();

    }
```

//Observer instance

```
public class InfosysStock : IObserver
    {
        private ISubject _subject;
        private double _latestvalue = 0;
        public InfosysStock(ISubject subject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
            _subject.Register(this);
        }



        public void update(double value)
        {
            _latestvalue = value;
            display();
        }

        private void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The latest value is : " + _latestvalue);
        }


        public void unsubscribe()
        {
            _subject.UnRegister(this);

        }
    }
```

//Subject Instance

```
public class StockMarket : ISubject
    {

        List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>();
        public int _stockvalue = 0;

        public void setValue(int v)
        {
            _stockvalue = v;
            notify();
        }

        public void notify()
        {
            foreach (var observer in observers)
            {
                observer.update(_stockvalue);
            }
        }

        public void Register(IObserver o)
        {
            observers.Add(o);
        }

        public void UnRegister(IObserver o)
        {
            int idx = observers.IndexOf(o);

            observers.RemoveAt(idx);

        }



    }
```

Finally the main class

```
StockMarket stockmarket = new StockMarket();
InfosysStock infy = new InfosysStock(stockmarket);
stockmarket.setValue(15);
stockmarket.setValue(21);

            infy.unsubscribe();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is not how it is supposed to be used. `setValue` should automatiacally _notify_ listeners. Having to call `notify` manually is pointless and makes the whole pattern unnecessary.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have modified the code. Does it look fine now? any other modifications  to be made?

Comment: Is this just to learn?  why not use the built in interfaces and reactive extensions?

Comment: I am implementing it newly and would like to get the feedback if the approach is right?

Answer (score 3):

### 1. If you are implementing this pattern for learning, then it is OK.

Otherwise, you can use built-in [Observer Pattern of C#.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-implement-an-observer)

### 2. Think about readable:

> ```
>     public void UnRegister(IObserver o)
>     {
>          int idx = observers.IndexOf(o);
>
>          observers.RemoveAt(idx);
>
>      }
>
>
>  }
> ```

There are some redundant empty lines in your code. Inaddition, **"o"** is not a good variable name. I think you can change it to "observer".

### 3.You don't need to retrieve index of an object and then you remove it via the index. It will reduce the performance:

> ```
>       public void UnRegister(IObserver o)
>       {
>           int idx = observers.IndexOf(o);
>
>           observers.RemoveAt(idx);
>
>        }
> ```

You can use Remove() method to remove an object from the list directly:

```
    public void UnRegister(IObserver o)
    {
        observers.Remove(o);
    }
```